# Modelmapper returns null instead user id

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have 2 entities, wired by One-To-One dependency.

User:

```
public class User {

    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserParams params;
    ...
}
```

UserParams:

```
public class UserParams {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

I transform it with ModelMapper:

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.getConfiguration()
            .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT)
            .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
            .setSkipNullEnabled(true)
            .setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull())
            .setFieldAccessLevel(PRIVATE);
    return mapper;
}
```

I'll explain how mapper works. I exclude 'user' field from UserParams mapping & map it separately. This way, I reseive only ID of 'user' field for UserParams & full dto 'params' for User.

```
//exclude from mapping
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    mapper.createTypeMap(UserParams.class, UserParamsDto.class)
            .addMappings(m -> m.skip(UserParamsDto::setUser)).setPostConverter(toDtoConverter());
    mapper.createTypeMap(UserParamsDto.class, UserParams.class)
            .addMappings(m -> m.skip(UserParams::setUser)).setPostConverter(toEntityConverter());
}

//map separately
@Override
protected void mapSpecificFields(UserParams source, UserParamsDto destination) {
    whenNotNull(source.getUser(), u -> destination.setUser(u.getId()));
}

@Override
protected void mapSpecificFields(UserParamsDto source, UserParams destination) {
    whenNotNull(source.getUser(), u -> destination.setUser(userRepository.findById(u).orElse(null)));
}
```

Postconverters realize transformation:

```
protected Converter<E, D> toDtoConverter() {
    return context -> {
        E source = context.getSource();
        D destination = context.getDestination();
        mapSpecificFields(source, destination);
        return context.getDestination();
    };
}

protected Converter<D, E> toEntityConverter() {
    return context -> {
        D source = context.getSource();
        E destination = context.getDestination();
        mapSpecificFields(source, destination);
        return context.getDestination();
    };
}
```

Than, when I call UserParams (by /params?id=1), I reseive JSON with filled user:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "created": "2019-06-13T20:07:52.221",
    "updated": null,
    "user": 1,
    "height": 180,
    "weight": 75,
    "gender": null,
    "birthDate": null
}
```

But when I call user, field params transforms to dto, except field user:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "created": "2019-06-13T19:50:16",
    "updated": null,
    "params": {
        "id": 2,
        "created": "2019-06-13T19:50:22",
        "updated": null,
        "user": null,    //null
        "height": 180,
        "weight": 75,
        "gender": null,
        "birthDate": null
    }
}
```

As I understand, when maps User, mapper not call postConverter for nested objects, I checked using breakpoints. Why? What to do?
Project [here](https://github.com/promoscow/modelmapper-demo2).

Comment: "As I understand, when maps User, mapper not call postConverter of userParams. Why?" - well, that's for you to find out, is it? The name of the method "whenNotNull" implies that maybe your entities are not correctly mapped and your "user" is null?

Comment: no, user is not null, when I get it from repository, it exists in params. The problem is that mapper not call postconverter when mapping nested objects.